# Don't understand why PHP contact form is showing an error message and not sending

Tags: php, html, css

http://madaxedesign.co.uk/dev/contact.php

Hi,

I was wondering if anyone could tell me why when I fill out this form that I get it only gives me this message.

`You do not have permission to use this script from another URL, nice hacking attempt ;p.`

Instead of saying thank you and proceeding to send an email to my email client.

I'm still new to php so any help would be great.

Thanks

Comment: show us your code. No one can help without seeing `code` ;-) This is obviously a `referer` issue.

Comment: do you run this server from a vps? or from a shared host? do you have access to change the permission onf any of your files? have you set up any deny access requests in any .htaccess files?

Comment: Your form is at `/dev/contact.php`, but it's sending its data to `/contact.php` - is there something in the code in the latter file that checks the referring URL?

Comment: You obviously didn't write the code, so that error should be pretty self explanatory

Comment: mattedgod thanks for your useless trolling email.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, your `<form>` action is set to `/contact.php` and it should be either `/dev/contact.php` or just `contact.php` because you are already in `/dev/`.

I was able to successfuly submit a message by using Chomes inspector to change the form action.

Comment: Sounds as if there might even be a `security issue` if you were able to modify the form action (?)

Comment: In `Chrome` you can modify any `HTML` data.

Comment: That is why you should always escape all `POST`/`GET` data to protect your selves from potential injection attacks.

Comment: Always do; just thought there might be something else I wasn't aware of.

Comment: Thanks for your help on this. Thought it would be something stupid like that. Like I said I'm still new to php so good learning curve.